# How do you charge tax on the one thousand per every thousand in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an assignment where I am not receiving any help. My teacher wants us to do an excel project where someone makes between 24,000 and 34,000 dollars every year and they are charged 12 percent tax on their wealth in excess of 24,000 dollars; however, if their wealth is greater than 34000 they are charged 18 percent tax per the 1000 dollars they make ( I have no idea what this means).

I have tried using nested IF functions to solve this problem, however, I am not really sure where to start or what to do.

I am not trying to have anyone do my homework/project, I just sincerely need help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Start by looking up how to calculate marginal tax rates in excel](https://exceljet.net/formula/income-tax-bracket-calculation)

Comment: I think your teacher want you to build a tax brackets table with different range of income and applicable tax rates, then you can easily use **IF** + **VLOOKUP** for instance to calculate the tax based on the look up table.

Answer (score 0):

I may have read your question wrong, if the taxable amount is the portion above 24000 then you will need to adjust the calculations accordingly. However the two methods shown should get you some way...

1) with if statements like:

```
=if(A1>=34000,A1*0.18,if(A1>=24000,A1*0.12,"error"))
```

Or you can use vlookup() with a table :
[image]